Rows into Columns using PIVOT not correctly resulting
My table is like below



ColA
ColB
ColC
ColD
ColE
ColF




ABCD
EFGH
HIJK
R111
HIJK
20


ABCD
EFGH
XXXX
R111
XXXX
30


ABCD
EFGH
XXXX
R112
YYYY
40


ABCD
EFGH
zzzz
R112
zzzz
50



Output what I want is



ColA
ColB
ColC
R111
R112




ABCD
EFGH
HIJK
20



ABCD
EFGH
XXXX
30
40


ABCD
EFGH
zzzz

50



I tried using SQL PIVOT, but I keep getting parameter not valid error.
Essentially ColD,ColE and ColF is what I want to transpose where ColE and ColC are same.
Can someone help ?

"I tried using SQL PIVOT, but I keep getting parameter not valid error." you forgot to include that attempt and the full error. Though, honestly, forget PIVOT exists; use conditional aggregation.

The name "Sql_query" is not a valid identifier. I can't put the actual query/error here. Copy paste limitations unfortunately.
Funnily, the dynamic query does not run when i try exec @sql , but If I copy paste the query created in "sql" variable , it works. So i am really confused now.
For Conditional aggregration, there is nothing to aggregrate. It's more of a transpose where the ColD can have dynamic number of distinct values and those need to be converted into dynamic columns.

If you can't provide us with an [mre] of the problem, we can't help you. Code, however, can most certainly be pasted into [so] though.

I want to transpose where ColE and ColC are same... I don't understand the 2nd row in your desired output. Why is 40 listed? In the original data, ColE <> ColC for 40. One is XXXX and other is YYYY.

@Isolated  Cause I want to transpose column D , and show it's distinct content as my dynamic columns

But colC <> colE; therefore that violates your requirements, doesn't it?

ohh sorry , ColC is exactly same as ColE. a typo there.

Use the [edit] feature to demonstrate your attempts please. The comments are not the right place for them.

If ColE doesn't matter, then just remove from the question. If ColE matters, then you should add sample data and desired output that shows how it matters.

This is a pretty standard pivot. The wrinkle is that you want to ignore ColE, which is easiest done by removing it inside the subquery, something like:
select *
into #data
from (
    VALUES  (N'ABCD', N'EFGH', N'HIJK', N'R111', N'HIJK', 20)
    ,   (N'ABCD', N'EFGH', N'XXXX', N'R111', N'XXXX', 30)
    ,   (N'ABCD', N'EFGH', N'XXXX', N'R112', N'YYYY', 40)
    ,   (N'ABCD', N'EFGH', N'zzzz', N'R112', N'zzzz', 50)
) t (ColA,ColB,ColC,ColD,ColE,ColF)

select *
FROM    (
    select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColF
    FROM    #data
    ) x
pivot (max(colf) for ColD IN ([R111], [R112])) pv

As you see, i only select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColF which removes the unnecessary ColE-values.
Output:



ColA
ColB
ColC
R111
R112




ABCD
EFGH
HIJK
20
NULL


ABCD
EFGH
XXXX
30
40


ABCD
EFGH
zzzz
NULL
50



For dynamic pivot, you need to generate the [R111], [R112] part dynamically, which is just a simple DISTINCT query:
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @SQL = N'

select *
FROM    (
    select ColA, ColB, ColC, ColD, ColF
    FROM    #data
    ) x
pivot (max(colf) for ColD IN (' + STRING_AGG(CAST(QUOTENAME(ColD) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY ColD) + ')) pv'
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ColD
    FROM    #data
    ) x

EXEC(@SQL)

